# Problem with Numba jit nonpython and numpy: All templates rejected with literals

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am implementing a program that do random sampling in Python 3.6.7 and there is one function that I just can't get to compile with Numba. The most recent version of it is:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True) 
def bs_stat_numba(data, iter_n=1000):

    iter_mean = np.mean(np.random.choice(data, size =(len(data),iter_n))) 
    iter_std = np.std(np.random.choice(data, size =(len(data),iter_n)))

    bs_mean = np.float32(np.mean(iter_mean))
    bs_std = np.float32(np.mean(iter_std))

    return bs_mean, bs_std

data = [[1,2,3,4], [12,23,45,67], [10,11,12,23,45,6]]

zkzq_dict = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(data))):
    bs_mean, bs_std = bs_stat_numba(data[i])
    zqPre_upper = bs_mean + 2*bs_std
    zqPre_lower = bs_mean - 2*bs_std
    zkzq_dict.append([zqPre_lower, zqPre_upper])




Here is the error as follows:
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<function mean at 0x7f8b7c103730>) with     argument(s) of type(s): (float32)
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function mean at 0x7f8b7c103730>)
[2] During: typing of call at <ipython-input-244-488a401000dd> (8)


File "<ipython-input-244-488a401000dd>", line 8:
def bs_stat_numba(data, iter_n=1000):
    <source elided>

    bs_mean = np.float32(np.mean(iter_mean))
```

The versions that I am using are numba==0.45.1, numpy==1.17.2. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it make an difference if you use `data = np.array(data)`?

Comment: unfortunately, no. :(

Answer (score 1):

Now it works:

```
@jit(nopython=True) 
def bs_stat_numba(data, iter_n=1000):

    iter_mean = np.mean(np.random.choice(data, size =(len(data),iter_n))) 
    iter_std = np.std(np.random.choice(data, size =(len(data),iter_n)))

    bs_mean = np.float32(iter_mean)
    bs_std = np.float32(iter_std)

    return bs_mean, bs_std

data = [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([12,23,45,67]), np.array([10,11,12,23,45,6])]

zkzq_dict = []
for i in tqdm(data):
    bs_mean, bs_std = bs_stat_numba(i)
    zqPre_upper = bs_mean + 2*bs_std
    zqPre_lower = bs_mean - 2*bs_std
    zkzq_dict.append([zqPre_lower, zqPre_upper])
```

What I did?

1. I replaced list of **lists** (data) to list of **numpy arrays** (because
   Numba doesn't like reflected list). You question doesn't contain this error, but I got it when I tried to run your code, so I fixed it too.
2. I removed one of your **np.mean** from code, because, for example, **iter_mean** is already mean value, but you tried compute it one more time: **mean(iter_mean)**. There is no reason to compute mean from one value, so Numba doesn't like it to and returned TypeError (The error that I see in your question)